# Return ArrayList<String> in HIVE UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I've created a UDF function which takes two text arguments and return 
    ArrayList.
But when I call the UDF function in Hive, it gives me an error.

Here is a snippet of my UDF code:

```
public class MyTestUDF extends UDF {
    public ArrayList<String> evaluate(Text i, Text s) {

        if(s == null) return null;

        String id = i.toString();
        String value = s.toString();

        <parse string value to v1, v2, and v3, and apply logic>

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add(id);
        result.add(v1);
        result.add(v2);
        result.add(v3);

        return result;
    }       
}
```

And here is how I ran in Hive:

```
hive> SELECT multi[0] AS id,
             multi[1] AS value1, 
             multi[2] AS value2,
             multi[3] AS value3
      FROM (SELECT my_udf_function(id, data) AS multi FROM testDB) bar;

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10033]: Line 1:7 [] not valid on 
        non-collection types '0': struct<elementdata:struct<>,size:int>
```

The data is a giant string value that I parse and apply logic and return three values as a format of ArrayList.

I referred this link [Returning & Using Multiple Values from a HIVE UDF](http://paxcel.net/blog/returning-using-multiple-values-from-a-hive-udf/) but it doesn't work for me.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks fine, and it tests fine for me.  Is there any chance that your `my_udf_function` was aliased to some other UDF class by calling `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` with some class name different from your `MyTestUDF`?

Answer (score 2):

Change `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Text>`, because Hive requires serializable types such as `FloatWritable`, `IntWritable`, or `Text`.
For more information, I suggest [Returning & Using Multiple Values from a HIVE UDF](http://paxcel.net/blog/returning-using-multiple-values-from-a-hive-udf/), easy to read and explaining what to do after.

Comment: Could you clarify what you bean by "change ArrayList by ArrayList"? 
Also, please try to [always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (quoted from Stackoverfow's guidelines for good-quality answers).

Comment: OK. My answer gets some improvments by Markus and ryanyuyu. Thanks to them. To sum up, 'ArrayList<String>'  can't be understood by Hive. It needs another type **serializable** and in this case 'ArrayList<Text>' is perfect.